# How to make weak references in Java?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, weak-references

Let me explain it the following way:
you have an Object a holding a reference to an Object b.
you know that **if only a holds a reference to b**, then **b is not needed** anymore, and **should be collected by the GC**.

Now imagine, **a is always accessible**.

The gc realizes that **b can be accessed through a**.

Therefore, **the GC will never collect b!**

**How can i make the GC collect b if only a has a reference to it?**

**is there any way to make a reference that is ignored by the GC (weak reference),** so that when the above conditions are met, **the gc collects b, leaving a null pointer to a?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the tag "weak-references" in your question, and that's the answer right there. Java has a `WeakReference` class for doing just this, holding references to objects that can nevertheless still be garbage collected. If the object to which you have a `WeakReference` gets collected, the `WeakReference` returns null.

Comment: thanks. should i delete the question? Now it seems stupid to me. I thought java never would have something like this so i expected some hacky answer on stackoverflow to be the only way finding a solution.

Comment: Since a lot of people don't know about `WeakReference`, might as well leave the question around for other people to learn from.